# Unique Records in Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL table that will be be joined with two subtables. One of these subtables is a simple join, but the other will have either one or multiple records that correspond to one of the records in the parent table. I need to write a query that will return each record in the parent table and only the most recent record for each relevant record in the parent table.

So, for example:

### Parent Table

ParentID
ParentName
UserID
ParentBlahBlah

### SubTable1

UserID
UserName
UserGroup
UserCreated

### SubTable2

SubID
ParentID
SubName
SubBlahBlah

My query as it stands is something like:

```
SELECT * FROM ParentTable
  INNER JOIN SubTable1
    ON ParentTable.UserID=SubTable1.UserID
  INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM SubTable2) as Table2
    ON ParentTable.ParentID = Table2.ParentID
```

This is where I'm stuck. TOP obviously isn't right, as it only selects one row, not one row for each ParentID.

Am I at least on the right track here?

Comment: I should also add that I sort DESC by date in the subquery!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `CROSS APPLY`

```
SELECT *
FROM   ParentTable
       INNER JOIN SubTable1
         ON ParentTable.UserID = SubTable1.UserID
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
                    FROM   SubTable2
                    WHERE  ParentTable.ParentID = SubTable2.ParentID
                    ORDER  BY [date] DESC) ca
```

Comment: This did it - I wasn't aware of cross apply!

Comment: do you have a link to documentation for cross apply?

Comment: @Johan - 
[BOL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx) but [more relevant to this particular question](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/departments/optimizing-top-n-per-group-queries)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
WITH DAT AS
(
SELECT *,
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ParentTable.ParentID ORDER BY ParentID DESC) RN
  FROM ParentTable INNER JOIN SubTable1
    ON ParentTable.UserID = SubTable1.UserID INNER JOIN SubTable2
    ON ParentTable.ParentID = SubTable2.ParentID
)
SELECT *
  FROM DAT
 WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

in your second inner join instead of

```
(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM SubTable2)
```

use

```
(Select * from SubTable2 WHERE
 SubId in (SELECT MAX(SubId) FROM SubTable2 GROUP BY ParentID))
```

Comment: Assuming that later defined `SubId`'s have later dates.

Comment: That's right.. I don't think I can use this because of that. My part of the application will do inserts and generally this would be true... but someone else is developing another part of it and unfortunately I can't guarantee how their data will behave.